# Define a new font command

Tags: fonts, macros

I'd like to define a command aiming to apply italic and bold at the same time. I tried use `\newcommand{\itbf}{\textit{\textbf{}}}`. Is it correct?

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\itbf}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **aiming to apply italic and bold at the same time**?

Comment: @Sveinung Italic correction is the spacing applied after italic text to avoid awkward overlapping, like in `{\itshape f}f` (compare with `{\itshape f\/}f`, which contains the italic correction `\/`). The second form doesn't limit the bold italic text to the argument (try `\itbf{bold} still bold`).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik As usual, you are right. I wrongly assumed the {} worked as group.

Comment: @Sveinung Not _that_ usual ;-) It's an apparently common misconception. What would work would be to add the necessary group: `\newcommand{\itbf}[1]{{\itshape\bfseries#1}}`. The actual italic correction would still be missing, though.

Comment: @Levy it's work!

Comment: @andrew.paul.acosta -- An example of where a bold italic font is needed is in a biology paper, where a bold section heading contains a species name, which should be set in italic type.

Comment: @barbarabeeton:  Nonetheless, in a case like the one you describe, you wouldn’t need to define a font command that switches to that combination of series and shape: you would write, in the source file, something like `\section{About \emph{Mammalia}}`.

Comment: @GuM -- In that case, you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX provides the `\DeclareTextFontCommand` declaration precisely for this purpose; in your case, you should say, for example,

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbfit}{\bfseries\itshape}
```

That is, in the first argument you specify a name of your choosing for the new command; and in the second argument, you put the declarations needed to obtain the family, series, and shape you want to change to.

With this method, you define commands that behave *exactly* as the predefined commands `\textit`, `\textbf`, etc., in that

- they are robust, so they can be used without problems in “moving arguments”;
- they automatically take care of the italic correction at both ends,
  in a way that is consistent with what the predefined commands do
  (actually, by means of the same algorithm).

Indeed, the predefined commands `\textit`, `\textbf`, etc. are *themeselves* defined by means of `\DeclareTextFontCommand`, as you can readily check in the LaTeX sources (*e.g.*, in `latex.ltx`).  Note that, given this fact, the name you choose for your new command should, by consistency, begin with `\text...`.

MWE:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbfit}{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand*{\nonRobustCommand}{I'm not robust!}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\robustCommand}{I'm robust!}



\begin{document}

Normal text and \textbfit{text that is both boldfaced and italicized}.  By way
of comparison, \textbf{this is text that is oly boldfaced} (but not italicized),
and \textit{this is text that is only italicized} (but not boldfaced).

Test for italic correction:
\begin{itemize}
    \item
        bold-italic followed by normal: \textbfit{f}f
    \item
        bold-italic followed by bold: \textbfit{f}\textbf{f}
    \item
        bold-italic followed by italic: \textbfit{f}\textit{f}
\end{itemize}
In the last case, you might argue that the italic correction should 
\textbfit{not} be used, as in {\bfseries\itshape f}{\itshape f}, but that's the 
way \LaTeX\ is programmed!

\typeout{Test for robustness: \textbfit}
\typeout{(Compare with this: \nonRobustCommand}
\typeout{And with this: \robustCommand)}

\end{document}
```

---

## Addition

I forgot to mention, among the benefits of this approach, that your new command will automatically work in math mode too, if you load the `masmath` package (actually, it suffices to load the `amstext` package), as the predefined commands like `\textit` and `\textbf` do.

New MWE:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amstext}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbfit}{\bfseries\itshape}
\newcommand*{\nonRobustCommand}{I'm not robust!}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\robustCommand}{I'm robust!}



\begin{document}

Normal text and \textbfit{text that is both boldfaced and italicized}.  By way
of comparison, \textbf{this is text that is oly boldfaced} (but not italicized),
and \textit{this is text that is only italicized} (but not boldfaced).

Test for italic correction:
\begin{itemize}
    \item
        bold-italic followed by normal: \textbfit{f}f
    \item
        bold-italic followed by bold: \textbfit{f}\textbf{f}
    \item
        bold-italic followed by italic: \textbfit{f}\textit{f}
\end{itemize}
In the last case, you might argue that the italic correction should 
\textbfit{not} be used, as in {\bfseries\itshape f}{\itshape f}, but that's the 
way \LaTeX\ is programmed!

Compatibility with the \textsf{amsmath} (or \textsf{amstext}) package:
\( T_{\textbfit{bold-italic}} \ne T_{\textit{italic}} \ne T_{\textbf{bold}} \).

\typeout{--------------------------------}
\typeout{Test for robustness: \textbfit}
\typeout{(Compare with this: \nonRobustCommand}
\typeout{And with this: \robustCommand)}
\typeout{--------------------------------}

\end{document}
```

This time I’m also showing the output:

[image: Output of the second MWE]